# Can't update table 'usuarios' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla llamada 'usuarios' con 3 campos(codigo_usuario,nombre_usuario,clave_usuario) y quiero que al momento de insertar un registro el disparador me encripte la contraseña por el metodo codigo:

### Código

```
Delimiter $$
Create trigger encriptar_clave
before
Insert on usuarios for each row
Begin insert usuario(codigo_usuario,nombre_usuario,clave_usuario)
Values(codigo_usuario,nombre_usuario,aes_encrypt(clave_usuario,"fer123"));
END $$
```

pero me sale el siguiente error:

### Error

> #1442 - Can't update table 'usuarios' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Si la intención es que la contraseña se guarde *encriptada* entonces el `INSERT` no tiene nada que hacer ahi
- Por otro lado lo único que debería ocurrir es un previo al `INSERT` tomar el valor `NEW` de la contraseña y hacer lo que necesites con el.
- Para que de este modo cuando la acción de insertar se complete entonces el valor ya haya sido modificado
- Comprendiendo que el *trigger* se va a disparar cuando una acción sea llevada a cabo sea antes o después (*en este caso antes*)

De esta forma:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER modificaContrasena BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.clave_usuario = aes_encrypt(NEW.clave_usuario,"fer123");
END;
//
```

**Enlace para consultar mas al respecto**

- [sintaxis de triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS, es exactamente lo que quería..